# NSFetchResultsController delegate not getting called

Tags: ios, core-data, delegates, nsfetchedresultscontroller, core-data-migration

I am using the`NSFetchedResultsController` for loading my tableView using coredata.
Recently **I have added a new `Entity`** in my ManagedObjectModel and did coredata versioning and used light weight migration.

A print description of my Managed Object Context (MOC) shows the newly added Schema and schema is also defined in the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`.

My issue is that once I insert data in to the newly created `Entity` the **`NSFetchedResultsController` delegates are not getting fired** even though no error is thrown while insertion and I verified that insertions are indeed taking place in the SQL table.

I have checked whether coredata migration is required using

```
 NSMigrationManager *manager = [[NSMigrationManager alloc]
                               initWithSourceModel:[self sourceModel] destinationModel:[self destinationModel]];




BOOL success = [manager migrateStoreFromURL:storeURL type:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                    options:nil withMappingModel:mappingModel toDestinationURL:dstStoreURL
                            destinationType:NSSQLiteStoreType destinationOptions:nil error:outError];
```

and found that coredata is automatically selects the correct model and there is no need to use `NSMigrationManager`.

For implementing `NSFetchResultsController` i have followed examples from Raywenderlich

http://www.raywenderlich.com/999/core-data-tutorial-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller
and it used to work fine on CoreData without any versioning.

Can anyone tell me how to make `NSFetchResultsController delegate` work **after adding a new Entity** and doing versioning and I have `changed the Current Core Data Model` to the latest one  .There are no relation between newly added Entity and Old Entity in the Managed Object Model.

### EDIT:Here is my fetch results controller initialisation code

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

if (fetchedResultsController != nil) {
    return fetchedResultsController;
}

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                               entityForName:@"SongDetails" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                          initWithKey:@"songName" ascending:YES];


[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];



[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:10];

/*CHECKED WHETHER ANY SONGDETAILS ARE FETCHED*/
NSError * err;
NSArray * results = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&err];
NSLog(@" results >>> %@ ,results);
/* */

NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController =
[[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                    managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                               cacheName:nil];

self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

return fetchedResultsController;
```

}

After I added a Log in the fetch results controller I am getting the following results

```
 results >>> ("<SongDetails: 0x115abae0> (entity: SongDetails; id: 0x115a94a0 <x-coredata://7E5CDD40-8A4C-455D-8000-34FD70AC8837/SongDetails/p1> ; data: <fault>)",
"<SongDetails: 0x115abe90> (entity: SongDetails; id: 0x115aa450 <x-coredata://7E5CDD40-8A4C-455D-8000-34FD70AC8837/SongDetails/p2> ; data: <fault>)",
```

Again following are the results from the SQL debugger while insertion.

```
2013-03-06 12:09:25.894[6035:c07] CoreData: sql: BEGIN EXCLUSIVE
2013-03-06 12:09:25.895[6035:c07] CoreData: sql: INSERT INTO ZSONGDETAILS(Z_PK, Z_ENT, Z_OPT, ZSONGNAME) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)
2013-03-06 12:09:25.902[6035:c07] CoreData: sql: COMMIT
```

Any help will be  appreciated.

Comment: you should post the code where you initialize the `NSFetchedResultsController` including the `NSFetchRequest`. Changing your model definition (i.e. adding an entity) doesn't effect whether an 'NSFetchedResultsController` will detect a change, it depends on the `NSFetchRequest` and if/how it is affected by your data change.

Comment: So i hope that adding new entity and setting coredata to proper version will not effect the fetch results controller.Is there any thing else that I need to take care in a similar case.

Comment: ok, the `NSFetchRequest` is configured for the entity `SongDetails` so if any `SongDetails` object changes the `NSFetchedResultsController` delegate methods will be called (as long as you implement them). Why do you think the `delegate` methods aren't working?

Comment: Yes i tried inserting SongDetails in the view did load after initializing MOC and FRC but nowhere the delegate seems to be informed about the insertion.

Comment: still more code would be helpful. where are you calling `performFetch` for the FRC? Also your `viewDidLoad` code as relates to the FRC and `SongDetails`.

Comment: Thanks dude it helped ,if you could put the answer below i can give give a upvote.I was in a impression that performFetch is not needed so was just initialising the fetch results controller.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25650/discussion-between-prajul-and-xjones)

Comment: Glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Paraphrasing from my comments. You need to call `[fecthedResultsController performFetch:&error]` before the FRC will detect model changes and call its delegate methods.